# Jqueryを使ったMonacaで画面のどまんなかに文字を表示させる方法について

Tags: monaca, css

すみません。質問させてください。

MonacaでjQueryを利用してページを作成しているのですが、1点詰まったことがあります。

画面の縦横の真ん中に文字を表示させように、

htmlで

```
<div id="startFl" data-role="page" height="100%">
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr height="100%"> 
        <td class="mainscreen"><p id="call_text_Fl"></p></td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

CSSで

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
td.mainscreen{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

として、見たのですが、横では中央に表示されたのですが、縦では真ん中になっていませんでした。
これは何が良くないのでしょうか。

お知恵をお貸しください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div>` タグに `height` という属性は存在しないため、CSSで指定する必要があります。

加えて、`<td>` や `<tr>` の幅・高さは自動調整されるため、`100%` を指定する必要はありません。

```css
html, body, #startFl {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.mainscreen {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="startFl" data-role="page">
  <table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="mainscreen"><p id="call_text_Fl">hoge</p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

テーブルのレイアウトを再現する `display: table` 等を使えば、`<table>` タグも不要になります。

```css
html, body, #startFl {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#startFl {
  display: table;
}
.mainscreen {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="startFl" data-role="page">
  <div class="mainscreen"><p id="call_text_Fl">hoge</p></div>
</div>
```

`.mainscreen` の高さが決まっている場合など、条件によっては他の方法が使えることもありますが、テーブルに頼るのが簡単ではあります。詳しくは「css 上下中央」等で検索してみてください。

Comment: 返事が遅くなりまして申し訳ありません。
ありがとうございました。
意外と単純な方法で、びっくりしました。

他にフォントサイズなど要素を追加したければ、これを基本に追加すればいいのですね。